# Get an image source from another page

Tags: html, image, cross-domain

I have PAGE-1 and PAGE-2

On PAGE-1 I want to have and image with a source link similar to one on PAGE-2 (on a particular domain or the particular order image)

```
<img src="*source of a particular image on PAGE-2*" />
```

How is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: downvoted because linking to an image, whether internal or external, is one of the first things you learn in HTML and therefore would be very easy to find in Goodle...or ANYWHERE.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the absolute url of the image to use in the src like this

```
<img src="http://192.***.*.**/xyz/abc/myImage.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you basically want to number to be dynamic in PAGE-X.

Let's say you have 2 pages, PAGE-1.html and PAGE-2.html: (Both with same content, of course you can edit yourself later)

```
<script src="js.js"></script>

<body onload="page()">
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Both linked to the same source file js.js

```
function page(){
url = window.location.pathname;
filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '<img src="images/' + filename + '.png">';
}
```

and you have 2 images named the same as PAGE-1.html and PAGE-2.html, but with an extension .png. Therefore both images are called `PAGE-1.html.png` and `PAGE-2.html.png`.

Whenever `PAGE-1.html` is loaded, it will automatically call `PAGE-1.html.png` becasue the name is the same. Same goes to `PAGE-2.html`, it will load `PAGE-2.html.png`. Therefor if you want more pages such as `PAGE-3.htm`l, `PAGE-4.html` etc.. Simply add the same image name to your image source like `PAGE-3.html.png` and `PAGE-4.html.png`